# Best way of doing this in php

Tags: php

I'm currently working on a game and I want a function like this, there will be 100 if statements if I do it like this, is there a better way of doing it?

```
$bulletzz = 10000;
$sum = $bulletzz /10;

if($healthh <=1){
$bulletzz = $sum *0.1;
/// reducing the damage the bullets do if they have 1 health etc
}elseif($healthh <=2){
$bulletzz = $sum *0.2;
/// reducing the damage the bullets do if they have 2 health etc
}elseif($healthh <=3){
$bulletzz = $sum *0.3;
/// reducing the damage the bullets do if they have 3 health etc
}elseif($healthh <=4){
$bulletzz = $sum *0.4;
/// reducing the damage the bullets do if they have 4 health etc
}elseif($healthh <=5){
$bulletzz = $sum *0.5;
/// reducing the damage the bullets do if they have 5 health etc
}
```

Comment: This may be suitable for Code review. Why are you assigning `$sum` in each condition if it's the same value?

Comment: This has nothing to do with PDO...

Comment: Yes simple math just do this $bulletzz = $sum * ($healthh / 10);

Comment: The logic is strange. You count `$sum` using `$bulletzz` and than count `$bulletzz` using `$sum`, calculated a line before? WTF?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the only thing that changes is the multiplier that is applied to the `$sum`, this should work:

```
$sum = $bulletzz / 10;
$bulletzz = $sum * (ceil($healthh) / 10);
```

That's because the multiplier is always 10 times less than the rounded up value of `$healthh`, based on the example you have given. To round a number to the next integer, use `ceil()`.

Also, based on the "100 statements..." phrase, I believe that `$healthh` must be capped within the range of 0 to 100. If that's the case, add an additional clause before to ensure `$healthh` is always coerced to between 0 and 100:

```
$healthh = max(0, min($healthh, 100));
$sum = $bulletzz / 10;
$bulletzz = $sum * (ceil($healthh) / 10);
```

Comment: I've edited my post, if they have 1 health, their bullets would only do 0.1* the damage. 2 health would be 0.2* etc etc

Comment: @Chris  please close a question when you find the right answer. Check: [How to accept an answer?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235)